# Create a DIV with dynamically expanding width?

Tags: html, css

I have an interface with some `<a>` tags, at the end is a div with some more `<a>`'s that has a `display:none` attributed to it. When the user clicks a button, it fires some javascript that unhides the hidden div. The problem is I have a border around the containter div, and want it to expand when I unhide the nested div. The issue is that all my  anchor tags, in and out of the hidden div, just list horizontally unless I specify a fixed-width. Any help

(aside: Would a `<span>` be better here over a `<div>` for the hidden portion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (aside: Would a  be better here
>   over a   for the hidden portion?

`span` is completely different than a `div`. If as per your design needs you need a block-level elemnts (the one you could give `width` to), go for a `div` else `span` should be fine.

If you want the links to appear vertically, you should apply this style to them:

```
div a{
  display:block;
}
```

Or probably:

```
div a{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want to maintain the inline characteristics of the links as well.

Answer (score 0):

Markup required I think, but it sounds like all you want is your anchor tags to repeat vertically not horizontally - so just give them `display: block` no?

And no this doesn't sound like a case for a span particularly since the semantic value is a collection of non-inline child elements.